# Name of ForeignKey Back Relation?

Tags: foreign-key, relational-theory

Table `detail` has a ForeignKey to table `master`.

How to call the back relation?

> `master` has ??? to table `detail`

I could not find a canonical word in wikipedia or other resources.

Comment: `master` is a `parent` to `detail`?

Comment: `master` is referenced in/by `detail`?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminology used to to talk about conceptual design of database, this is called **inverse relationship**. So you could say:

> `master` has an inverse relationship with table `detail`.

See for instance: *Fundamentals of database systems*, by R. Elmasri, S. Navathe, Addison Wesley, ISBN: 978-0-13-608620-8, Chapter 11, Object and Object Relational Databases.